# i want to create labels within these tuples

Tags: python

hello i want to create a list within these tuples so that it prints the label next to the code Example "Purchase date = 23 Aug 16 , purchase price = 43.50 and so on but i keep getting the "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

```
portfolio = ( "23-Aug-2016", 43.50, 25, 'CAT', 92.45 ),
( "15-Mar-2014", 42.80, 50, 'DD', 51.19 ),
( "7-Dec-2015", 42.10, 75, 'EK', 34.87 ),
( "6-Dec-2014", 37.58, 100, 'GM', 37.58 )

purchase , okay, shares, symbol, current = portfolio

print("Purchase date =", purchase)
print("Purchase price =", okay)
print("Shares =", shares)
print("symbol =", symbol)
print("Current price =", current)

i = 0
while i < len(portfolio):
print(portfolio[i])
i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`portfolio` is a tuple that contains just a single tuple.

```
>>> portfolio = ( "23-Aug-2016", 43.50, 25, 'CAT', 92.45 ),
>>> ( "15-Mar-2014", 42.80, 50, 'DD', 51.19 ),
(('15-Mar-2014', 42.8, 50, 'DD', 51.19),)
>>> ( "7-Dec-2015", 42.10, 75, 'EK', 34.87 ),
(('7-Dec-2015', 42.1, 75, 'EK', 34.87),)
>>> ( "6-Dec-2014", 37.58, 100, 'GM', 37.58 )
('6-Dec-2014', 37.58, 100, 'GM', 37.58)

>>> portfolio
(('23-Aug-2016', 43.5, 25, 'CAT', 92.45),)
```

As you can see, only the first tuple is included because the assignment statement ends on that line. Because it ended with a comma python has created a outer tuple wrapping the one that you defined. For example:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x
1
>>> x = 1,
>>> x
(1,)
>>> 2,
(2,)
```

this assigns the tuple `(1,)` to `x` in a manner similar to your code. Each of the following lines in your code creates a tuple, but it is not bound to any variable so it is lost, just as it was for `2,` above.

You can unpack the inner tuple by referencing it by index:

```
>>> purchase, okay, shares, symbol, current = portfolio[0]
>>> purchase
'23-Aug-2016'
>>> okay
43.5
...
>>> current
92.45
```

You were probably expecting a tuple (or list) of tuples. You can do that by wrapping the entire expression in `(` and `)` (or `[]` for a list):

```
portfolios = (("23-Aug-2016", 43.50, 25, 'CAT', 92.45 ),
                ( "15-Mar-2014", 42.80, 50, 'DD', 51.19 ),
                ( "7-Dec-2015", 42.10, 75, 'EK', 34.87 ),
                ('6-Dec-2014', 37.58, 100, 'GM', 37.58))
```

Now you can *iterate* over the tuples:

```
for portfolio in portfolios:
    purchase, okay, shares, symbol, current = portfolio
    print(purchase, okay, shares, symbol, current)
```

**Output**

```
23-Aug-2016 43.5 25 CAT 92.45
15-Mar-2014 42.8 50 DD 51.19
7-Dec-2015 42.1 75 EK 34.87
6-Dec-2014 37.58 100 GM 37.58
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

```
portfolio = [( "23-Aug-2016", 43.50, 25, 'CAT', 92.45 ),
    ( "15-Mar-2014", 42.80, 50, 'DD', 51.19 ),
    ( "7-Dec-2015", 42.10, 75, 'EK', 34.87 ),
    ( "6-Dec-2014", 37.58, 100, 'GM', 37.58 )]

for item in portfolio:
    purchase , okay, shares, symbol, current = item
    print("Purchase date =", purchase)
    print("Purchase price =", okay)
    print("Shares =", shares)
    print("symbol =", symbol)
    print("Current price =", current)
```

Some things to note:

- `portfolio` should be a `list`
- iteration is done using `for thing in iterable` in Python